# XMPP Server - Strophe - I cannot join on the server with my webclient

Tags: xmpp

I have my own xmpp server. At: jenan.cz

Why can not I connect via WebClient?

Error: **status CONNFAIL**

Application is here: http://jenan.cz/xmpp/

Connection in: http://jenan.cz/xmpp/gab.js

I use the following connection:

```
$(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {
    var conn = new Strophe.Connection(
        "http://jenan.cz:5280/http-bind/");

    conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {
           if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('connected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('disconnected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.ERROR) {
            alert ('status ERROR');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
            alert ('status CONNECTING');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
            alert ('status CONNFAIL');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.AUTHENTICATING) {
            alert ('status AUTHENTICATING');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL) {
            alert ('status AUTHFAIL');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.ATTACHED);
            alert ('status ATTACHED');

    });

    Hello.connection = conn;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the http-bind module in ejabberd:

```
{modules,
 [
{mod_http_bind, [{max_inactivity, 120}]}
]}.
```

Change settings for 5280 port:

```
  {5280, ejabberd_http, [
       {request_handlers,
         [
          {["http-bind"], mod_http_bind}
         ]},
       http_bind
       web_admin
       ]
    }
```

Change connection settings:

```
$(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {
    var conn = new Strophe.Connection(
        'http://jenan.cz:5280/xmpp-http-bind');

      conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {
           if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('connected');
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            $(document).trigger('disconnected');
        }

    });


    Gab.connection = conn;
});
```